# Minimum set of array masks with fixed width n spanning a given array x

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, numpy-ndarray

`x` is a `numpy` array of `0` and `1`. `n` is an arbitrary integer such that `n <= len(x)`. Using `x`, create a list `y` of `boolean` arrays such that:
(a) Each array in `y` is exactly same size as array `x` with value `True` or `False`.
(b) Entries at the gap of `n` should be `True` and rest are `False`.
(c) Each `1` in `x` should have exactly one `True` value in only one of the arrays in `y`. In remaining arrays of `y` the corresponding entry must be `False`.

**For example:**
**1.** If       `x = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1])`

Desired outputs for different `n` are:

```
n=2 : [[True, False, True, False, True]]
n=3 : [[True, False, False, True, False],
       [False, True, False, False, True]]
n=4 : [[True, False, False, False, True]]
n=5 : [[True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, True]]
```

**2.** If       `x = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])`

Desired outputs for different `n` are:

```
n=2 : [[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False,], 
       [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]]
n=3 : [[True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True], 
       [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False], 
       [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False]]
n=4 : [[True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False], 
       [False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False], 
       [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False], 
       [False, True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True]]
n=5 : [[True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False], 
       [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False], 
       [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False], 
       [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True]]
```

Note in reality both `x` and `n` can be decently large to the order of 4000 and 100 respectively.

Comment: Is there guarantee that such solution exist for your input `x` and `n`?

Comment: @Ehsan yes that is by definition. Given we have a solution below (may not be optimal) you can try & clarify those cases where you think the solution may not exist.

Comment: please see if the suggested solution resolves the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
y = np.zeros((n, x.size), dtype=bool)
for i in range(n):
    y[i,i::n] = True
y[np.flatnonzero((y*x).sum(-1))]
```

You definitely can substitute the loop with a faster numpy methods, however I assume your `n` is not too large and the loop should not be a bottleneck.

output for `x = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])` and `n=5`:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, True]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan this is a very elegant solution. Quick one: do you need `np.flatnonzero` or `np.nonzero` would do? Also, any specific reason to do `sum(-1)` and not do `sum(1)`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "faster numpy methods"?

Comment: @Gerry using loops in numpy is not advised and numpy benefits more from avoiding loops. The for loop in the question can probably be replaced using `roll` or `pad` or some other similar methods that are faster by nature of numpy.

Comment: I noticed that `nonzero` returns tuple but somehow `y[np.nonzero((y*x).sum(-1))]` works as well as `y[np.nonzero((y*x).sum(-1))[0]]`

Comment: You are right, since it is a 1-D array and numpy accepts tuple indices, that might not be necessary. Either should work and would not be different in speed I think.

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan do you have an example to show how to replace for loop with `roll` or `pad` in this case.

Comment: @Gerry Not particularly. But I am fairly certain you can do it with such methods. Deleting comments to clean up the post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to do it very inefficiently. Can someone suggest a faster solution?

```
Y = []
x_temp = x.copy()
y = np.zeros(len(x_temp), dtype=bool)
y[::n] = True
cnt = np.sum(x_temp)
i = 0
while (cnt > 0) and (i < n):
    if np.sum(x_temp*~y) < cnt:
        Y.append(y)
        x_temp = x_temp*~y
        cnt = np.sum(x_temp)
    y = np.roll(y, 1)
    y[:1] = False
    i+=1
```